# Why jQuery Slider doesn't work on my wiki?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, mediawiki

**JQuery slider on wiki's main page which I'm moderator doesn't work.** Code is exactly same as wiki's english version (I work on french version) but my version doesn't work. You can see comparions [here][1] and [here][2]. I don't know what to do.

This is Javascript code of the slider:

```
mw.loader.using(["jquery.cookie"]);

mw.loader.using(["jquery.ui"], function() {
  $(".portal_vtab").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
  $(".portal_vtab > ul > li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");

  var $tabs = $("#portal_slider").tabs({
    fx: {
      opacity: "toggle",
      duration: 100
    }
  });

  $(".portal_sliderlink").click(function() { // binding click event
    $tabs.tabs("select", this.className.match(/portal_sliderlink-(\d+)/)[1]);
    return false;
  });
  $(".portal_next").click(function() { // binding click event
    var selected = $tabs.tabs("option", "selected");
    $tabs.tabs("select", selected + 1); // switch to next tab
    return false;
  });
  $(".portal_prev").click(function() { // binding click event
    var selected = $tabs.tabs("option", "selected");
    $tabs.tabs("select", selected - 1); // switch to previous tab
    return false;
  });
});
```

And this is link to css code: [here][3] and another to the template Slider generator which is also used: [here][4].

I updated JavaScript code on MediaWiki v1.37 in changing "jquery.ui.tabs" to "jquery.ui" and nothing.
I typed positive value in text-indent function on

```
.portal_slide 

    .portal_buttons a {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

and nothing. So i cancelled this change.
I changed URLS on background fond images of CSS code and always nothing.

---

Edit of 14/07/2023/

At the end I even changed order of ImportJS page'scripts to put them in alphabetical presentation. NO-THING!!
And this is my wiki's CSS, in case of the problem come from here: [5].

[1]: https://onepiece.fandom.com/fr/wiki/One_Piece_Encyclop%C3%A9die       [2]: https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/One_Piece_Wiki                   [3]: https://onepiece.fandom.com/fr/wiki/MediaWiki:Slider.css         [4]: https://onepiece.fandom.com/fr/wiki/Mod%C3%A8le:Slider_generator
[5]: https://onepiece.fandom.com/fr/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share a running snippet or a link to a running example. Actual code examples are way more helpful than screenshots since you can easily reproduce a code error. Better avoid code screenshots - some users might downvote your question for the aforementioned reasons. See also ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you tried shuffling the order of the ImportJS scripts? The snippet you attached is present in the generated bundles, but the event listener is not actually registered, unlike on the English version, where the scripts are placed in a different order in MediaWiki:ImportJS

Comment: Yes, i've changed scripts order in MediaWiki:ImportJS to put them in alphabetic order but are you really sure that scripts order matters in their functioning? I'm a amateur programmer ok, but i find that hard to believe.

Comment: So? What do you think?

Comment: @user15517071 Huh? What do you think of that I've said? Is it possible that script order has influence on their functionning or not?

Comment: `@user15517071` Hello?

Comment: Sorry, I have been taking a break. To answer your question, I don't know. I am not particularly familiar with how ImportJS works, but I've looked around and this seems like the only discrepancy between the English and French versions, and it's entirely possible Fandom's media viewer takes precedence over the slider script due to this alone. If I were you I would try and see if that makes any difference. There will be virtually no harm.

Comment: @user15517071 Ok so i'd tried and there isn't any differences. The slider doesn't even work. What do you think?

Comment: `@user15517071` If needed, this is [wiki css]: (https://onepiece.fandom.com/fr/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css)

Comment: `@user15517071` Hello? Are you here?

Comment: `@user15517071` I repeat: I shuffled ImportJS script's order to make it correspond to the english version but it doesn't work! So? If needed, this is wiki CSS: (https://onepiece.fandom.com/fr/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css)

Comment: `@Robis Koopmans` Hello! It's again me. Can you precize that you've written to me many days ago? Where do you see that module jquery.ui.tabs isn't on my wiki?

Comment: @Robis Koopmans Hello! It's again me. Can you precize that you've written to me many days ago? Where do you see that module jquery.ui.tabs isn't on my wiki?

Comment: `@Robis Koopmans` `@user15517071` So, no need to answer me now. It works right now, due to good advices given by Comunity Central forum's members. Thanks agains for all!